# What is the '}{' character that appears in LyX modern CV example and how to re-produce it?

Tags: lyx, moderncv

I'm using LyX 2.0.6 with MikTex 2.9

I came across these `}{` characters while trying to use the Modern CV example to create a CV.

My question is: What are these and how can I insert one.

I've noticed that the language tag must have two of these (i.e., `}{` `}{` ), computer tag must have three and the normal entry must have 5. Also document wouldn't render if one was missing from a certain tag.

Note: currently I'm copying and pasting from other places in the document.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I do not understand the question.  Can you provide a link to a document (or the document itself) containing the characters that you're referring to?

Comment: The document can be found here: [link](http://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyx-devel/branches/BRANCH_2_0_X/lib/examples/modernCV.lyx). It also exists in C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\examples\modernCV.lyx

Comment: Please edit your question to include the link.

Comment: And which lines should we look at?

Comment: I wouldn't know exactly which lines correspond to the `}{` character as I'm a novice, however, this [link](http://www.lyx.org/trac/export/40977/lyxsvn/lyx-devel/branches/BRANCH_2_0_X/lib/examples/modernCV.lyx) should allow you to download the .lyx file in which you'd be able to find such `}{` characters (for example paragraph 4 under education. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{` is an opening brace, and `}` is a closing brace. TeX/LaTeX (which is used by LyX 'under the hood') uses these e.g. to delimit groups and arguments to macros. I don't know exactly how LyX does this with `moderncv`, but say you have a macro that takes four mandatory arguments, then in LaTeX you would write

```
\somemacro{first argument}{second argument}{third argument}{fourth argument}
```

So each pair of `{}` encloses an argument. If LyX somehow hides the opening and closing braces, then perhaps you would only see the three pairs of `}{`, which are part of two different groups/arguments.

**Note:** For LyX to interpret these as actual code, and not a symbol to be inserted in the text, they have to be written within an ERT, that you add with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert --> TeX code).

As for how to insert them, that depends on which keyboard layout you have. With an English layout for example, they are usually inserted with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> I think, while with a Norwegian keyboard it's <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>. Therefore the details will depend on your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That explanation of yours makes sense because when I check the LaTeX Source (View->View Source) I can see this `\cventry{2003--2006}{Master of Economics}{Institution}{City}{Country}{Description}` which appears in LyX as `Entry: 2003--2006}{Master of Economics}{Institution}{City}{Country}{Description`. I could add similar ones which did the trick but now I guess I'm wondering how would I know how many arguments a tag (e.g., `\cventry` in this case) should have and what each argument should represent (for instance year, certificate, institute). Thanks again.

Comment: @has981 Well, `moderncv` doesn't have a proper manual that I know of, so the only way is to read the code in the [examples](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples) (edit:) and compare with the typeset PDFs.